# Manual update to marshmallow possible for rooted phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Can an unlocked phone such as Moto be updated to Marshmellow upon release, or are we stuck waiting for Motorola or the carrier?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the manufacturer makes a version of the ROM for the device or not - if they do, then you'll probably be able to get your hands on a stock ROM and flash it onto your device. Some custom ROM developers may create custom ROMs which are based on marshmallow too, which would allow users of that device to experience marshmallow, especially if it won't be/isn't yet available for that specific device.